# Set doctrine entities attribute in cascade (Symfony2 app)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working in a Symfony2 application (using Doctrine) where that contains the following entities:

- A (name, description, isDeleted, b)
- B (name, description, isDeleted, c)
- C (name, description, isDeleted)

  A->B->C

One of the Apps requirement is we must keep in the database all the rows and just set them as deleted in case we need to remove an A, B or C from the database.

Currently every entity has a Manager service that allow to us managing and working with the entities.

However when we need to remove one element of the entities A (isDeleted = true) we must to trigger an action for setting as isDeleted = true all the children relations, in this particular case we need to set as deleted B and C.

Is there any design pattern or good practice (using event dispatcher, doctrine life cycles event or Service way) to achieve this ? In order to keep the code clean and maintainable if we need to add more relationship.

Thanks.

Comment: Doctrine Life cycles won't be triggred if you use native query. I'd recommand using event dispatcher. When you delete entities you should trigger an event, and into the bound listeners you should update the suitable other entities

Answer (score 1):

I think Soft Delete Extension is good enough for this

https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md

http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/soft-delete-extension.html